# Changing same vector element from multiple work-items, OpenCL

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm processing a vector in OpenCL kernel and outputting results in the other vector. It happens so that multiple input vector elements can output in the same output vector element.

Code is currently not working and I'm wondering if that is a known limitation to OpenCL computing.

```
__kernel void search_sort_particles(__global float4* p_pos, __global int* cell_particles, __global int* cell_number_of_particles, float4 lb, int4 c_n, float c_size)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    int max_cell_particles = 20;


    int4 c_pos;    // determine cell position
    c_pos.x = floor((((p_pos[i].x - lb.x) / c_size)));    
    c_pos.y = floor((((p_pos[i].y - lb.y) / c_size)));    
    c_pos.z = floor((((p_pos[i].z - lb.z) / c_size)));   

    int c_idx = c_pos.x + (c_n.x * c_pos.y) + (c_n.x * c_n.y * c_pos.z);        // determine cell index

    // store particle index in cell
    cell_particles[c_idx*max_cell_particles + cell_number_of_particles[c_idx]] = i;
    cell_number_of_particles[c_idx]++;
}
```

As you can see from the kernel, each particle position p_pos[i] (about 3000 in the simulation) is processed to yield its cell index c_idx (around 1000 cells total).

Then cell_number_of_particles[c_idx] is incremented to remember particle's presence in the cell. And some of the particles will increment the same cell index.

Comment: There are atomic functions for this kind of stuff. Atomic add for example, returns old value atomically, adds New value atomically.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Thank you very much, it works now with atomic functions!